# Perform operation on index of a Pandas series that has been grouped

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to group a Pandas series based on values and then perform an aggregating operation on the index of the series.  Pandas isn't recognizing me passing ser.index.

```
dti = pd.date_range("2021-05-13", periods=6, freq="H")
ser = pd.DataFrame({'Value': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']}, index=dti)
ser.groupby('Value')[ser.index].min()
```

If your proposed solution is converting the series into a DF, then note that in my actual use-case, I'm incorporating the above into a function that I will apply on every single column of a large dataframe.  So not clear how to pass the index to every column either.

```
dti = pd.date_range("2021-05-13", periods=6, freq="H")

col1 = pd.Series(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'])
col2 = pd.Series(['a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': col1, 'col2': col2})
df.index = dti

df.groupby('col1')[df.index].min()
```

Comment: `df.sort_index().groupby('col1').head(1)`

Comment: Or `df.index.to_series().groupby(df['col1']).min()`.

Comment: why dont you drop the duplicates after sorting the index if necessary: `ser.sort_index().drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your index to series:

```
>>> df.index.to_series().groupby(df["col1"]).min()
col1
a   2021-05-13 00:00:00
b   2021-05-13 02:00:00
c   2021-05-13 03:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```